# Set displayed text of HyperLink on RadGrid load

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I have a telerik RadGrid that gets populated with data from a SQL database when the grid loads. The first column lists a name, which needs to be a hyperlink to another part of the website. I have tried a couple different options, neither of which gets me the results I need.

The first way I tried was using a GridHyperLinkColumn. However that does not allow me to change the displayed text of the hyperlink programmatically when the grid gets populated with data.

```
<telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlFields="joblink" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/Job.aspx?id={0}" Text="JobName">

taskDR.Item("joblink") = dataReader("publicID")
taskDR.Item("joblink").Text = dataReader("name")  'This is what I would like to do
```

The other option was to use a GridBoundColumn and bind a Hyperlink to it.

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="joblink" UniqueName="joblink">

Dim jobhyperlink As New HyperLink()
jobhyperlink.Text = dataReader("name")
jobhyperlink.NavigateUrl = "/Job.aspx?id=" & dataReader("publicID").ToString()
taskDR.Item("joblink") = jobhyperlink
```

However instead of displaying the hyperlink in the joblink column, all that displays is "System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink"

I looked into the DataTextField and DataTextFormatString properties of GridHyperLinkColumn, but I couldn't find a way to alter those fields programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

```
<telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn UniqueName="joblink" Text="jobname" DataNavigateUrlFields="joblink" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/Employer/Job.aspx?action=edit&id={0}" DataTextField="jobname" DataTextFormatString="{0}">

Dim taskDT As New DataTable
taskDT.Columns.Add("jID")
taskDT.Columns.Add("jobname") 'You need one column for the DataTextField
taskDT.Columns.Add("joblink") 'and another for the DataNavigateUrlField

While dataReader.Read()
Dim taskDR = taskDT.NewRow()
taskDR.Item("jobname") = dataReader("name")
taskDR.Item("joblink") = dataReader("publicID")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try a template column and just place a html  tag and use Eval function to bind the things the way you want.

Check out this demo - http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/columntypes/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Also, rather than using eval and html tag you can use a(n?) asp:HyperLink and change the text and NavigateURL in the ItemDataBound. I think using a template is cleaner.